# How to replace the zoom ring on a Nikon 18-200 lens?

Tags: lens, nikon, repair, diy

The zoom ring (the rubber-band part) on my Nikon 18-200 is a little stretched out.  What is the best way to replace this?

I already had to remove the black sticker on the front of the lens when the filter threads came loose, so I'm mostly wondering, since the threads seem a fair amount larger than the rest of the lens, if I should remove the filter threads before replacing the ring, and wait to replace the sticker until that's done, or if it's just as easy to replace the ring on an intact lens.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to contact either your lens manufacturer or local Camera Repair shop.

Often the manufacturer can help you track down a replacement part and order allow you to order it. You could then attempt to replace the part. Sometimes the band slips over however sometimes it requires you to disassemble your lens which isn't recommended!

Alternatively get in contact with a local repair shop they will have vast knowledge regarding your lens and be able to help you put quickly and sometimes cheaply (depending on the work required).

If it doesn't affect the lenses performance maybe it's worth just living with it?

I know from experience taking a lens apart really dosent end well!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this dpreview thread](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3353320), you can just get a replacement rubber replacement ring on eBay/Amazon and pull off the old one and pull the new one on. It's simply friction fit, so it's basically just like playing with a big rubber band; no need to disassemble the lens.  It doesn't look like they're original Nikon parts, but for the low cost and high likelihood of repeated replacement, maybe it doesn't matter.